# How to control multiple ajax request from different js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request, joomla2.5

I am using joomla to make a component and several modules releated to it. I have red several post about multiple ajax request. But I didn't find any post about ajax request from different js files.
I have one module it works like facebooks notificatins in a simpler manner. When the page is loaded it sents the request every predefined seconds to control if the user has new offer from another. If it finds any it shows a message buble ower the notif button. when user clics the button it fires an other request to pull the offers in a list in opend little layer like facebook. I control the arrangemnt of request by making an global variable like ajax and initialize with a value of 1. If a request start then the 0 is assigned to the var ajax. if it returns success it returns 1 again an before every request it checks the value of var ajax to start. But Now I need to make an other module to refresh the content for every predefined seccond to bring the list of new contenbt form the database. Or in the component I need to mage the pagination via the ajax for inbox and outbox of user offers. How to control all of these. Without crashing. I though that insert some codes here but lines are very much and the won't tell any thing in addition to that I told.

I will be thankful to he/she who aswer my question. Have a good day.

---

```
    var checkInt = setInterval(checkUnreadeds,3000);
var ajax = 1;
function checkUnreadeds(){
    if(ajax == 1){
        $mc.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  'url-here',
                    data: 'task=getUnreadeds&tmpl=component&member='+$mc("#drapanelbutts").attr('member'),
                    success: function(data,status, xh) {            
                                var ex = data;                                              
                                ex = ex.split("|");
                                    if(ex[0] !=0){
                                        $mc("#offerCount").html(ex[0]).css('display','block');
                                    }
                                    if(ex[1] !=0){
                                        $mc("#messageCount").html(ex[1]).css('display','block');
                                    }   
                                ajax = 1;

                             }
        });
    }

}
```

this is the code form module for notification, but I should make some code which should repeat the request which update the content of module, for some interval like above one but how to prevent to request collapse.

Comment: Some code might help. Also, I don't know anything about joomla, but whether or not the ajax call is in a different file shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: As a short version of above. I have multiple ajax requests and one of them repeat every predefined seconds by useing setIterval(somefunction,3000); But I have these multiple request in different js files. So I couldnt control the queue by creating a global variable and checikn its value. How to control multiple requests in different file while one of them has infinit repeap.

Comment: Are you under the impression that different files don't share global state in javascript? If so, you are mistaking. Also you need to define "control".

Comment: that global variable is in the module's js file to control just the notfication control request and the request which is fired when notification button is click and then fill the content with notifications... But as I said I need an other repeatable requests to fill another module content with the other module's js file